# How can I implement trailing in flutter listtiles like the picture? (up right)

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can I implement trailing in flutter listTile like the picture? (up right)

[image]

Comment: You can use trailing property of ListTile widget, for more details about ListTile [read here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

you must make a custom Tile, unfortunately, the "ListTile" class has some height limitations.

Look this is a template you could use, there's literally any widget you could build mixing these essential widgets.

```
Container(
      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 56,
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Container(
                width: 56,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
              const SizedBox(width: 12),
              Column(
                children: [
                  Text('Title', style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6),
                  Text('Subtitle',
                      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
          const Icon(Icons.more_vert)
        ],
      ),
    );
```

Happy Coding!